# getting a list after a map() function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following python program

```
ml = [x for x in range(1,4)]
f = lambda x : x*2

print(f(ml))

nl = map(f,ml)
print(nl)
```

The output is given below.

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
<map object at 0x1005fada0>
```

`map()` is returning a `map object` is it possible to turn that into a list?

Comment: Unlike 2.7, map returns an iterator in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using python 3.x. Cast the `map` object to a list.

```
n1 = list(map(f,m1))
```

For a reference, read from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Send it to `list()`.

```
n1 = list(n1)
```